# x86 Assembly program does not terminate

Tags: assembly

I am learning assembly and my task was to convert a simple program from 32 bit to 64 bit. The program computes 2^3 + 5^2. My program compiles fine, however, when I run it the program does not terminate. Therefore, I have to Ctrl + C in the command line to actually stop the program. I was thinking that the problem initially was because I used `int 0x80` to terminate, but after I switched to `syscall` the problem persisted.

The code:

```
  1 .section .data
  2 .section .text
  3 .globl _start
  4 _start:
  5         push $3
  6         push $2
  7 
  8         call power
  9         addq $8, %rsp
 10 
 11         push %rax
 12 
 13         push $2
 14         push $5
 15 
 16         call power
 17         addq $8, %rsp
 18         pop %rbx
 19 
 20         addq %rax, %rbx
 21 
 22         movq $1, %rax
 23         syscall
 24 
 25 .type power, @function
 26 power:
 27         push %rbp
 28         movq %rsp, %rbp
 29         subq $4, %rsp
 30 
 31         movq 8(%rbp), %rbx
 32         movq 12(%rbp), %rcx
 33 
 34         movq %rbx, -4(%rbp)
 35 
 36 power_loop_start:
 37         cmpq $1, %rcx
 38         je end_power
 39 
 40         movq -4(%rbp), %rax
 41         imulq %rbx, %rax
 42         movq %rax, -3(%rbp)
 43         decq %rcx
 44         jmp power_loop_start
 45 
 46 end_power:
 47         movq -4(%rbp), %rax
 48         movq %rbp, %rsp
 49         pop %rbp
 50         ret
```

I'm sorry for posting this much code, but I need guidance as I am totally clueless. I've searched for a long time with no avail. Thanks in advance. BTW, the program works before converting it to 64 bit. I simply changed all `movl` etc to `movq` and used 64 bit registers.

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger.  Do some debugging.  Then ask.

Comment: @IraBaxter Sorry, I'm trying to debug with gdb. I've only had 2 days to learn assembly so debugging it is confusing for me as well.

Comment: Understood.    I suggest you start your program under gdb with PC at .start.  Step *one* instruction at a time.  Look at the registers carefully, to make sure you understand exactly what the instruction did.  If it did something that surprises you, go read about it until you know why.  Don't assume *anything*.   Learn about "step-into" vs "step_over" (seriously!).  This is part of the learning process. Do this for a few hours.  yes, the first time is painful; it gets a lot easier as you do more. Your understanding will improve enormously, and you will probably find your bug.

Comment: Tyler's answer here is all about "don't assume anything", including your assumptions (plural) that 64 bit assembly is just 32 bit assembly with 32 bit instructions changed to 64 bits.

Comment: @IraBaxter Ok thanks! I'll report back if I find anything.

Comment: @IraBaxter I got the program to actually terminate. I changed realized that the stack frame is multiples of 8 instead of 4.

Comment: OK, one broken assumption found.  Are you sure have all the bugs knocked out?  Stay with the debugger until you understand what all the program steps are doing.  Its *your* education.

Comment: @IraBaxter Hi, after debugging I realized that there was no logical faults. The program executed successfully. However, I wanted the value to get return as an exit code. Therefore I forgot to move rdx to rdi. In this case I lacked knowledge and debugging would've just made me more confused. Are there any good assembly books you recommend? I really want to understand assembly.

Comment: Debugging would have helped you find it.  You stare at the exit call, which is documented to have and exit code in RDI (or wherever), and the debugger shows a rediculous number in the exit code register.  Your conclusion? You forgot to move the value you wanted to RDI.  Debugging shows the actual state of affairs; if that state is wrong and the program doesn't work, then you have to change to code so the state is different.  The best way IMHO to get to understand assembler is *write* a *lot* of it, and then debug it all.  ...

Comment: ... if you really want to understand assembler, I suggest you read the Intel manuals describing the x86 processor from cover to cover, and then try to use that knowledge.  Look here: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html  Yes, that's a lot.  Welcome to education.  (Yes, I've done what I just recommended to you.  Took me awhile.  They are pretty well written.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using 1 as the system call number, but [it seems](http://blog.rchapman.org/post/36801038863/linux-system-call-table-for-x86-64) that it is actually 60. Apparently, you can't assume the syscall numbers aren't the same from 32bit linux to 64bit.

Upon further inspection, it seems there is a few more things wrong.

- You don't pass args on the stack in 64bit (unless you have so many they won't fit in the given regs. Look up the linux 64bit calling convention)
- In main, you push 2 dwords, but in power you get 2 qwords off the stack.

All the places you use `movq` to access memory are likely not working as expected, because the accesses are meant for dwords. You're reading or writing the higher 32bits of the number without meaning to.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the program still hangs:(